# Website help and color changing and centering

Tags: html, css

My Navbar text is currently not centered on the page, and the background color is white. I'd like the text to be vertically centered, and I'm hoping to match the Navbar's background color to the color of my main page.On my main page, I'm having trouble centering my name and interests. I'd like both elements to be perfectly centered both horizontally and vertically.I have three images with accompanying texts that I want to display in a row. Right now, they are not aligned correctly, and I'd like to raise both the images and texts a bit. I'm aiming for a neat and tidy row of images with their corresponding descriptions.If you could guide me on how to achieve these changes using HTML and CSS, I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Personal Project</title>

  <!--  bootstrap and aos  -->
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/aos.css">

  <!--  css   -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <section id="mainPage">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="main-display">
            <h1 id="name-title">Mazin Esmail</h1>
            <h2>Software Developer</h2>
            <h2>Student</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="about-me">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="heading-about">
          <h1 id="about--me" class="display-5">About me</h1>


          <p id="border-line-about"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="about-page-text">
      <p>Hello!, I am a student at Cal State San Bernardino and I am studying the field of computer science. I love going out to view new things and play the sports that I love. As an aspiring software engineer I want to solve real life problems and create
        web applications to further thrive a positive impact to the world. </p>


    </div>

    <div class="about-me-pics">
      <figure id="las-vegas-pic">
        <img src="assets/img/IMG_0525.jpeg" height="400" width="400" />
        <figcaption>Las Vegas, Nevada</figcaption>
      </figure>

      <figure id="basketball-pic">
        <img src="assets/img/IMG_0816.jpeg" height="400" width="400" />
        <figcaption>Fontana, California</figcaption>
      </figure>

      <figure id="mountain-pic">
        <img src="assets/img/IMG_2825.jpeg" height="400" width="400" />
        <figcaption>Fontana, California</figcaption>
      </figure>

    </div>
  </section>
```

```
  @font-face {
    font-family: Oswald;
    src: url("../fonts/Oswald-Medium.ttf");
  }
  
  html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
  
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Oswald, serif;
  }
  
  
  
  /* Center the navbar */
  .navbar {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .nav-link-home {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url(https://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/images1/Shadows-Backgrounds-HD.jpg);
  }
  
  .nav-link {
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .navbar * {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 100%;
  }
  
  .nav-item {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .nav-link-home {
    color: white;
  }
  
  #mainPage {
    background-image: url(https://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/images1/Shadows-Backgrounds-HD.jpg);
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    color: aliceblue;
  }
  
  .main-display {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%; /* Center vertically */
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  
  @keyframes fadeInOut {
    0%,
    100% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  
  #about-me {
    background-color: lightblue;
    min-height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  #border-line-about {
    position: relative;
    top: 100%;
    left: 22%;
    margin-top: 90vh;
  }
  
  #content-text {
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -888%;
    left: -42%;
    position: fixed;
    position: absolute;
    top: -70vh;
  }
  
  .about-me-pics {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 2rem; /* Adjust spacing between pics */
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  
  #las-vegas-pic {
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 330px;
  }
  
  .about-me-pics figure {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  #basketball-pic {
    transform: translate(-60%, 0%);
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  #mountain-pic {
    transform: translate(-40%, -0%);
  }
  
  .about-page-text {
    margin-top: 2rem; /* Adjust spacing as needed */
  }
```

Comment: You are using bootsrap...use `d-flex` on the outer element along with `align-content-center` and `justify-content-center` and you are done with positioning

Comment: why i am seeing two html confused here

Comment: sorry I fixed the mistakes with the files